# Using wild cards in the arguments for a bash script

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script which copies the last line containing a particular string from a bunch of similarly named files to a new file.

For example I have three files: 1abc1.txt, 2abc2.txt and 3abc3.txt.
From these three files i want to extract the last line containing the term "pass" and write those extracted lines to a new file named "ABC.txt".

The following is the bash script I came up with: (pass.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

grepline pass "$1" 1 > $2
```

Then I issued the following command:

```
./pass.sh *abc*.txt ABC.txt
```

But it doesn't create the ABC.txt file. Instead it scans for the string "pass" only in 1abc1.txt and then writes the output to 2abc2.txt .

I am supposing that my use of wild cards while issuing the command is not correct. Please can anyone suggest how to achieve what I want to do with the script?

Comment: since grepline isn't a standard part of any library (that I'm aware), you should link to its doco here (or correct me).

Comment: `*abc*.txt ABC.txt` as arguments will get expanded into matching file names so will fill the arguments array accordingly, not only argument 1 and 2 but add as many arguments as there are matching filenames.

Comment: Its not a standard part of any library. It is a part of a program that I use. By issuing the following command :  grepline text abc.txt 1      I am telling the script to scan the file abc.txt for string "text" and give back the last line where the string occurs.

Comment: Lea Gris, I think I understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcards are expanded by the shell before your script is executed, so actually you execute

```
 ./pass.sh 1abc1.txt 2abc2.txt 3abc3.txt ABC.txt
```

If you need to pass wildcards to your script you should quote this argument, and then let the shell expand it within the script

```
./pass.sh '*abc*.txt' ABC.txt
```

and the script should contain

```
grepline pass $1 1 > $2
```

Comment: So one good solution would be to remove the redirection from the script and put it in the command line.

Comment: I almost suggested the same thing.  there's a good argument to be made for not redirecting output in scripts - the invoker is likely to be better informed about how they'd like the output to flow, than the author.

Comment: Beta, your suggestion does work but for some purpose I have to do this using the scipt